# Nested columns with DataFrame in Streamlit data_editor?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

Looking to implement **nested columns** in a **Streamlit data_editor** like the attached image. Any tips or pointers?

[image]

I attempted to create nested columns within the **dataframe** but the cells are not editable(data_editor).

Also, **I want to know** if I can create **complex tables** using the **data_editor**.

[image]

**Code:**

- Python 3.12.2
- Streamlit, version 1.32.2

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

data = { 
    'col1': {
        'row 1':[1,2,3],
        'row 2':[1,2,3],
        'row 3':[1,2,3]
        },
    'col2': {
        'row 1':[1,2,3],
        'row 2':[1,2,3],
        'row 3':[1,2,3]
        }
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
st.data_editor(df, num_rows='dynamic')
```